# How does `ng serve` implement .htaccess?

Tags: angular, .htaccess

I am using Angular 9. When I modify .htaccess the local deployment does not change. This is true even for a simple 301 redirect. How does `ng serve` make use of .htaccess and how can it be modified in a local environment?

Answer (score 1):

`ng serve` is not using `.htaccess`. Angular CLI serves your application in their own simple http server, it's not Apache. And `ng serve` is only for develop purposes, not for production